# Gerar estes Resultados em PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como é gerado este tipo de resultado... Como ele é formatado desta maneira.

```
Mes/Ano | Vencidos | A Vencer | Vencendo
01/2015 |    5     |    0     |     0
02/2015 |    1     |    0     |     0
04/2015 |    15    |    0     |     0
06/2015 |    7     |    0     |     0
07/2015 |    1     |   200    |     3
09/2015 |    0     |   578    |     0
12/2015 |    0     |   231    |     0
```

É algum programa em específico que faz isso?

Comment: que faz o que? formatar a saida Mes/Ano ? ordenação? não entendi.

Comment: Tipo, você tem um SQL e executa ele, e ele vem esse tipo de resultados... eu já vi em várias questões mas não tenho idéia como ele gerou esse resultado... manualmente que não foi

Comment: Como assim, você quer dizer a formatação da tabela como texto?

Comment: André, podes dar exemplo de "eu já vi em várias questões"? e explicar melhor a pergunta? Não consigo perceber o que procuras...

Comment: É bem a resposta que foi postada, só que não sei como acessar o mysql no cmd..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acesse o path onde esta instalado o mysql, no meu caso estou usando o xamp mas uma instalação padrão geralmente fica na pasta *"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x\bin"*

```
C:\>cd xampp/

C:\xampp>cd mysql

C:\xampp\mysql>cd bin

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
```

O comando -u root indica o usuario -p indica que irá solicitar senha

[image]

Depois botão direito, selecionar tudo, Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V aqui no site:

```
    mysql> select usu_id, usu_nome, cancelado from tab_usuario limit 10;
+--------+----------+-----------+
| usu_id | usu_nome | cancelado |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | maison   | NULL      |
|      2 | marcio   | NULL      |
|      3 | marcos   | NULL      |
|      5 | celso    | NULL      |
|      6 | denise   | NULL      |
|      7 | camila   | NULL      |
|      8 | kelen    | NULL      |
|      9 | ingrid   | NULL      |
|     10 | eliziane | NULL      |
|     11 | felippe  | 1         |
+--------+----------+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Obs:** no caso do EasyPHP que foi o caso do autor da pergunta então o caminho para chegar até a pasta onde o mysql esta instalado seria:

***C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\bin***